# Using CoreData Model with Slide Menu View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I used a separate library of code to create my CoreData model. It works fine in a standalone app.

However I am using RESlideMenu and want to import this code into that. I have added all the code and connecting everything up, but when the app tried to load the viewController, I get the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'AddressBook'
```

After this, the app crashes!

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You'll have to show the code that crashes. All we can tell from this is that you're trying to do something like `[NSEntityDescription entityForName:nil]` or something along those lines.

Comment: Oh, and the slide menu has no effect on anything with core data. This is something to do with your code. Possibly a variable that is nil or something.